# use getimagesize() when upload is via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using [this file uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) and decided to validate actual content of the uploaded file to make sure that it is indeed an image. So I wanna use The PHP `getimagesize()` function which takes filename.
But there is no `$_FILES['xxx']['tmp_name']` so I pass it to `getimagesize` function. What do you recommend to validate actual content type in my upload process?

```
/**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */
class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {    
        $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $temp = tmpfile();
        $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        fclose($target);

        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    }
    function getImageInfo() {
        return getimagesize($_GET['qqfile']); /* no such file or directory */
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . $ext)){
    // if only images are allowed to upload
    if ($imgOnly)
    {
            // get image size and if $imgInfo were false delete uploaded file
        $imgInfo = getimagesize($uploadDirectory . $filename . $ext);
        if (!$imgInfo)
        {
            unlink($uploadDirectory . $filename . $ext);
            return array('error' => 'The file uploaded is not actual image file.');
        }
    }
    return array('success'=>true);
} else {
    return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
        'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `save` takes a string parameter and saves the uploaded image to a file with that path. So just open whatever filename you are passing to `save()`.

Comment: but it's not pre-upload, right? with this approach file uploads first and then must be check if it's valid or not. but it's still uploaded already

Comment: @mhesabi: Of course. How would it be possible to check a file with server code before the file arrives at the server?

Comment: may be files upload in a temp directory first like when we use $_FILES['xxx']['tmp_name']. `[tmp_name] => E:\xampp\tmp\phpCD2F.tmp`. not directly in upload folder.

Comment: @mhesabi: The files are uploaded to a temp directory and then immediately copied to their destination (why not directly? I don't know!) -- all this happens inside `save()`, which is 10 lines of code.

Comment: ok then, updated my code. so when save completed, I'm checking file with `getimagesize` and if returned false the uploaded file will be deleted.